# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end objective c

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, garbage-collection

I am trying to make an iOS app for inserting data in database and I have  passing 4 arrays in an url using JSON to insert values in database and sending it to server side in php file but I am getting such error -

```
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end".
```

But when I am trying to run that php file from browser then am getting successfully inserted message.

Here is my app side code

```
    NSString *url_string = [NSString 
    stringWithFormat:@"itemid[]=%@&itemname[]=%@&ReqQty[]=%@&         ItmUnits[]=%@&SiteFrom=%@&SiteTo=%@&        ReqDate=%@",_itemcode,_itemname,_ReqQty,_ItmUnits,_site_from.text,_site_to     .text,_date.text];;
    NSLog(@"%@",url_string);

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://anantsoftcomputing.com/ConstructSkills/require_test.php?format=json"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlrequest setHTTPBody:[url_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//  NSLog(@"%@",urlrequest);
  NSURLSessionDataTask *datatask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlrequest completionHandler:^(NSData *dataRaw, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataRaw options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
//   NSString *status = json[@"status"];
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    NSLog(@"count : %@",[json description]);

}];

[datatask resume];
```

and here is my php code

```
    <?php

     ini_set("display_errors","on");
     include 'db_connect.php';


    //request master
    $req = "INSERT INTO requirement_master (req_id) values (null)";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$req);
    //echo $res;
    $reqid = mysqli_insert_id($con);

    //singal variables
    $sitefrom = $_REQUEST['SiteFrom'];
    $siteto = $_REQUEST['SiteTo'];
    $reqdate = $_REQUEST['ReqDate'];

   // array variables // will get values from url as array format
    $idarray = implode(",", $_REQUEST['itemid']);
    $namearray = implode(",", $_REQUEST['itemname']);
    $reqarray = implode(",", $_REQUEST['ReqQty']);
    $unitarray = implode(",", $_REQUEST['ItmUnits']);

  //remove %20

  //will remove square bracets from your string return by implode

  $x =trim($idarray,'()');
  $a = str_replace(' ','',$x);
  $b =trim($namearray,'()');
  $c =trim($reqarray, '()');
  $d =trim($unitarray, '()');
//$e =trim($rcvqtyarray, '()'); 
//$f =trim($qtydiffarray, '()'); 

//will convert your array values into string
  $itemid = explode(",",$a);
  $itemname = explode(",",$b);
  $reqqty = explode(",",$c);
  $itemunits = explode(",",$d);

  $c = count($itemid);

// start inserting values to respective table
for($i=0; $i< $c; $i++)
 {

   $query = "INSERT INTO requirement_form          (Reqitem_id,req_id_master,item_name,quantity_req,units,site_from,site_to,date) VALUES 
      ('$itemid[$i]','$reqid','$itemname[$i]','$reqqty[$i]','$itemunits[$i]','$sitefrom','$siteto','$reqdate')" ;

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query); 

   echo $result;

  if($result)
  {
      $flag['code']= "Successfully registered";
      $flag['id'] = $reqid;
  }
  else
  {

      // $flag['code']= "Database query failed";
      $flag['code']= mysqli_error($con); 
   }
      echo json_encode($flag); 
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: I think you need to talk this issue with backend developer

Comment: did you first break the issue to understand whether your APIs are proper, by means of simulating through Postman like utilities?

Comment: i think APIs is proper because when i pass data from url in browser its show me data in JSON form